# ¿Cómo escribir un const char* en un std::stringstream anónimo?

Tags: c++, c++98

Tengo que escribir varios mensajes de depuración en un programa y quiero hacerlo con una macro usada tal que así :

```
TRAZA( "Hola" << " var=" << var );
```

Esta macro debe construir una cadena de caracteres con el fichero y la línea en que se encuentra en el código fuente y el mensaje entre paréntesis, por ejemplo, si `var` vale 7 , está en el fichero '/src/a.cpp' y en la línea 30 debe construir esta cadena :

> /src/a.cpp:30 - Hola var=7

Y debe llamar a la función traza(const char*) con esa cadena.
Obsérvese que en el parámetro de la macro quiero poder poner varios objetos encadenados al estilo de los `ostream` de c++ usando el operador `<<`.
La macro primero la implementé de la siguiente forma :

```
#define TRAZA( msg ) \
 do { \
    std::stringstream sstr; \
    sstr << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " - " << msg; \
    traza( sstr.str().c_str() ); \
 } while (false)
```

Que funciona bien salvo si tengo que imprimir una variable llamada `sstr`, la cual quedaría oculta por la declarada en la macro.

Intenté solucionarlo utilizando un objeto anónimo para no tener que declarar una variable :

```
#define TRAZA( msg ) \
 do { \
   traza( \
       dynamic_cast<std::stringstream&>( \
         ( std::stringstream() << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " - " << msg)) \
         .str().c_str() \
        );  \
 } while (false)
```

Pero no me escribe el nombre del fichero sino que me escribe la dirección del puntero en hexadecimal :

> 0x401024:30 - Hola var=7

¿Cómo lo hago para que el `std::stringstream` anónimo interprete que debe escribir la cadena de caracteres y no la dirección que apunta a esa cadena?

El programa siguiente tiene un ejemplo completo :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define TRAZA( msg ) \
 do { \
   traza( \
       dynamic_cast<std::stringstream&>( \
         ( std::stringstream() << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " - " << msg)) \
         .str().c_str() \
        );  \
 } while (false)

void traza( const char* texto )
{
    //   En realidad traza() hace otra cosa pero por simplificar
    // lo imprimo en la consola.
    //   Yo no he implementado traza(), no la puedo cambiar y tengo que 
    // usarla.
    std::cout << texto;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int sstr = 7;
    TRAZA( "Hola" << " var=" << sstr );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema se produce porque el operador de inserción no tiene una sobrecarga específica para `const char*`. En su lugar tiene una entrada genérica para punteros `ostream& operator<< (void* val)`. Si en dicha función no se hacen chequeos, lo único que se puede obtener de un puntero genérico es la dirección a la que apunta. En versiones posteriores, al menos de C++11 en adelante, el problema no se reproduce.

Una posible opción es usar el método `write` de `ostream`. Este método está sobercargado y, a diferencia del operador de inserción, incluye una  sobrecarga específica para `const char*`. De esta forma se evitan las ambigüedades y la cadena se puede volcar sin problemas.

Otro detalle interesante es que, al igual que el operador de inserción, la función `write` retorna una referencia del stream y esto permite concatenar llamadas.

```
#define TRAZA( msg ) \
 do { \
   traza( \
       static_cast<std::stringstream&>( \
         ( std::stringstream().write(__FILE__,strlen(__FILE__)) << ":" << __LINE__ << " - " << msg)) \
         .str().c_str() \
        );  \
 } while (false)
```

Por cierto, nota que he cambiado `dynamic_cast` por `static_cast`. Realmente sabes que el objeto es de tipo `std::stringstream`, luego un cast estático es más rápido ya que no realiza chequeos adicionales para verificar si la conversión puede ser realizada.